# What is the reason behind the following 'illegal inheritance' (Scala 2.9.2)?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, type-erasure, type-parameter

UPDATE: I rephrased my question with a smaller and more precise example.

Assume, we have the following definitions:

```
class A
trait TraitForA extends A

class D[T]
trait TraitForD extends D[A]
```

Then we can create an object like:

```
scala> new D[A] with TraitForD
res0: D[A] with TraitForD = $anon$1@145d424
```

But we can not create the following object:

```
scala> new D[A with TraitForA] with TraitForD
<console>:12: error: illegal inheritance;
 anonymous class $anon inherits different type instances of class D:
D[A] and D[A with TraitForA]
             new D[A with TraitForA] with TraitForD
                 ^
```

The same thing happens, when using a self type for the trait instead of `extends`:

```
scala> trait TraitForD2 { self: D[A] => }
defined trait TraitForD2

scala> new D[A with TraitForA] with TraitForD2
<console>:12: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type D[A with TraitForA] with TraitForD2 does not conform to TraitForD2's
selftype TraitForD2 with D[A]
              new D[A with TraitForA] with TraitForD2
                                           ^
```

What (exactly) is wrong with the creation above ?

My guess is, that `D[A with TraitForA]` is not seen as type `D[A]`. When using the covariant annotation `+T` in class `D`, both examples work.

Can somebody please explain the reason why the examples fail and why they are working with `+T` ?

Bonus question: Is there a way to get the examples run without `+T` ?

Comment: I think your explanation is mostly correct. Also consider that the type parameters are subject to erasure, so there is no way you could have the same trait mixed in with two different type parameters. I don't understand your last sentence (part of it being that it has a grammatical problem), maybe clarify that, as this seems to be your question ultimately.

Comment: @Sciss Thank you for the information. I rephrased my question.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. I corrected `trait TraitForA` for `trait TraitForA extends A` because I think that's the way it was meant by you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
class C[T]{ def f(t: T): T = t }
```

`C[A with Y]` says that it will have an `f` that will only take `A with Y`, and will only return `A with Y`.  `C[A]` cannot be satisfied by a function that will fulfill this request.  Therefore the two are in conflict.

Since type declaration success is not predicated on the details of the methods of any classes involved, `Z1 with Z2` or any other means of combining `C[A]` and `C[A with Y]` must be an error.

Answer (score 0):

To see the problem with variance, let's add some methods to the 'TraitForX'. For simplicity I will call those traits `A1` and `D1`, and I will also make `A` and `D` traits, again for simplicity. I don't know how you manage to come up with funny constructs -- I didn't know that a `trait` can even extend a `class`, it's weird that it is allowed!!

```
trait A
trait A1 extends A { def schoko = 33 }

trait D[T] { def result: T }
trait D1 extends D[A] {
   def result: A = new A {}
}
```

Now we know that we can do something with an instance of `A1` that is not possible with an instance of `A`. Furthermore, `D1` has a concrete implementation for `result`.

It is still possible to reproduce your cases:

```
new D[A] with D1    // works.

new D[A with A1] {  // works.
   def result = new A with A1 {}
   def test = result.schoko
}
```

You can see that `test` can invoke method `result` and, since `D` is parametrised with `A with A1` (which is the same as `A1` by the way), may subsequently call `schoko`.

It follows that the following can never work:

```
new D[A with A1] with D1 {
   def test = result.schoko
}
```

The compiler will say `value schoko is not a member of A`, which just means it refuses to accept that `D` is parametrised otherwise. `result` was implemented in `D1` to return an instance of `A` (which doesn't know `schoko`), so there is an inherent conflict here.

---

Now when `D` is changed to

```
trait D[+T] { def result: T }
```

(all the rest remains as above), you are just 'deferring' the problem:

```
new D[A with A1] with D1
```

The compiler now complains `error: overriding method result in trait D of type => A with A1` (you observed this as working because you didn't actually implement `result`).

So the variance annotation allows you to do certain things you couldn't before. If you hadn't implemented `result`, the following would be perfectly possible:

```
trait D2 extends D[A]

new D[A with A1] with D2 {
   def result = new A with A1 {}
}
```